# jellyfish C package not appearing in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have developed something using my home machines conda environment. I want to move this to a different user on the machine so I exported the environment to a environment.yml file. I done this via:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Then I created a environment on the other user:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

This creates the environment fine but when I got import `import jellyfish.cjellyfish` it doesn't find it.

example, on my user in ipython I can import it:

```
In [1]: import jellyfish.cjellyfish

In [2]:
```

Whereas, when I go use the environment in the other user:

```
In [1]: import jellyfish.cjellyfish
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5b03cb851b98> in <module>()
----> 1 import jellyfish.cjellyfish

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jellyfish.cjellyfish'
```

However, it does allow me to import

```
import jellyfish
```

Does anybody know how to get it so I can import `jellyfish.cjellyfish`?

Edit:

output of commands:

1) From my home environment (where cjellyfish works)

```
In [1]: import jellyfish.cjellyfish

In [2]: jellyfish.__file__
Out[2]: '/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/final_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jellyfish/__init__.py'

In [3]: jellyfish.__path__
Out[3]: ['/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/final_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jellyfish']
```

2) New environment (cjellyfish doesn't work)

```
In [1]: import jellyfish

In [2]: jellyfish.__file__
Out[2]: '/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jellyfish/__init__.py'

In [3]: jellyfish.__path__
Out[3]: ['/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jellyfish']
```

I run this command from within the new environment, i.e. `source activate final_env` then call `ipython`.

Upon request, here is the environment file:

```
name: final_env
channels:
  - riipl-org
  - pkgw/label/superseded
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - arrow=0.12.1=py36_2
  - arrow-cpp=0.9.0=py36h70250a7_7
  - awscli=1.15.51=py36_0
  - binaryornot=0.4.4=py36_0
  - boost-cpp=1.67.0=h3a22d5f_0
  - boto3=1.7.50=py_0
  - botocore=1.10.50=py_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.4.16=0
  - certifi=2018.4.16=py36_0
  - cookiecutter=1.6.0=py36_0
  - future=0.16.0=py36_0
  - fuzzywuzzy=0.16.0=py_0
  - jellyfish=0.6.1=py36_0
  - jinja2-time=0.2.0=py36_1
  - jmespath=0.9.3=py36_0
  - openssl=1.0.2o=0
  - parquet-cpp=1.4.0=h83d4a3d_2
  - poyo=0.4.1=py36_0
  - pyarrow=0.9.0=py36hfc679d8_2
  - pyasn1=0.4.3=py_0
  - pyperclip=1.6.2=py_0
  - python-levenshtein=0.12.0=py36_0
  - rsa=3.4.2=py36_0
  - s3transfer=0.1.13=py36_0
  - simplejson=3.16.0=py36_0
  - whichcraft=0.4.1=py36_0
  - zope.interface=4.5.0=py36h470a237_0
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py36he11e457_0
  - alabaster=0.7.10=py36h306e16b_0
  - anaconda-client=1.6.14=py36_0
  - anaconda-navigator=1.8.7=py36_0
  - anaconda-project=0.8.2=py36h44fb852_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astroid=1.6.3=py36_0
  - astropy=3.0.2=py36h3010b51_1
  - attrs=18.1.0=py36_0
  - babel=2.5.3=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - backports=1.0=py36hfa02d7e_1
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py36hfea85ff_2
  - beautifulsoup4=4.6.0=py36h49b8c8c_1
  - bitarray=0.8.1=py36h14c3975_1
  - bkcharts=0.2=py36h735825a_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blaze=0.11.3=py36h4e06776_0
  - bleach=2.1.3=py36_0
  - blosc=1.14.3=hdbcaa40_0
  - bokeh=0.12.16=py36_0
  - boto=2.48.0=py36h6e4cd66_1
  - bottleneck=1.2.1=py36haac1ea0_0
  - btrees=4.5.0=py36hf484d3e_0
  - bzip2=1.0.6=h14c3975_5
  - cairo=1.14.12=h7636065_2
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h9745a5d_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py36h0f667ec_1
  - click=6.7=py36h5253387_0
  - cloudpickle=0.5.3=py36_0
  - clyent=1.2.2=py36h7e57e65_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h489cec4_0
  - conda-verify=2.0.0=py36h98955d8_0
  - contextlib2=0.5.5=py36h6c84a62_0
  - cryptography=2.2.2=py36h14c3975_0
  - curl=7.60.0=h84994c4_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h93f1223_0
  - cython=0.28.2=py36h14c3975_0
  - cytoolz=0.9.0.1=py36h14c3975_0
  - dask=0.17.5=py36_0
  - dask-core=0.17.5=py36_0
  - datashape=0.5.4=py36h3ad6b5c_0
  - dbus=1.13.2=h714fa37_1
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - distributed=1.21.8=py36_0
  - docutils=0.14=py36hb0f60f5_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36h1aec115_2
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py36hd6bccc3_0
  - expat=2.2.5=he0dffb1_0
  - fastcache=1.0.2=py36h14c3975_2
  - filelock=3.0.4=py36_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py36_1
  - flask-cors=3.0.4=py36_0
  - fontconfig=2.12.6=h49f89f6_0
  - freetype=2.8=hab7d2ae_1
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0=haa9412d_0
  - gevent=1.3.0=py36h14c3975_0
  - glib=2.56.1=h000015b_0
  - glob2=0.6=py36he249c77_0
  - gmp=6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
  - gmpy2=2.0.8=py36hc8893dd_2
  - graphite2=1.3.11=h16798f4_2
  - greenlet=0.4.13=py36h14c3975_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1
  - gstreamer=1.14.0=hb453b48_1
  - h5py=2.7.1=py36ha1f6525_2
  - harfbuzz=1.7.6=h5f0a787_1
  - hdf5=1.10.2=hba1933b_1
  - heapdict=1.0.0=py36_2
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36h2f9c1c0_0
  - icu=58.2=h9c2bf20_1
  - idna=2.6=py36h82fb2a8_1
  - imageio=2.3.0=py36_0
  - imagesize=1.0.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2018.0.0=8
  - ipykernel=4.8.2=py36_0
  - ipython=6.4.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36hb52b0d5_0
  - ipywidgets=7.2.1=py36_0
  - isort=4.3.4=py36_0
  - itsdangerous=0.24=py36h93cc618_1
  - jbig=2.1=hdba287a_0
  - jdcal=1.4=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.0=py36_1
  - jinja2=2.10=py36ha16c418_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h006f8b5_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_4
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36he59e554_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36h7c827e3_0
  - jupyterlab=0.32.1=py36_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.10.5=py36_0
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h764f252_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py36h10fcdad_0
  - libcurl=7.60.0=h1ad7b7a_0
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=h6b74fdf_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng=7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
  - libgfortran-ng=7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
  - libpng=1.6.34=hb9fc6fc_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h1bed415_0
  - libssh2=1.8.0=h9cfc8f7_4
  - libstdcxx-ng=7.2.0=hdf63c60_3
  - libtiff=4.0.9=he85c1e1_1
  - libtool=2.4.6=h544aabb_3
  - libxcb=1.13=h1bed415_1
  - libxml2=2.9.8=h26e45fe_1
  - libxslt=1.1.32=h1312cb7_0
  - llvmlite=0.23.1=py36hdbcaa40_0
  - locket=0.2.0=py36h787c0ad_1
  - lxml=4.2.1=py36h23eabaa_0
  - lzo=2.10=h49e0be7_2
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36hd9260cd_1
  - matplotlib=2.2.2=py36h0e671d2_1
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py36h5ad9710_1
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36h14c3975_1
  - mkl=2018.0.2=1
  - mkl-service=1.1.2=py36h17a0993_4
  - mkl_fft=1.0.1=py36h3010b51_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h629b387_0
  - more-itertools=4.1.0=py36_0
  - mpc=1.0.3=hec55b23_5
  - mpfr=3.1.5=h11a74b3_2
  - mpmath=1.0.0=py36hfeacd6b_2
  - msgpack-python=0.5.6=py36h6bb024c_0
  - multipledispatch=0.5.0=py36_0
  - navigator-updater=0.2.1=py36_0
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36hb41ffb7_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h31c9010_0
  - ncurses=6.1=hf484d3e_0
  - networkx=2.1=py36_0
  - nltk=3.3.0=py36_0
  - nose=1.3.7=py36hcdf7029_2
  - notebook=5.5.0=py36_0
  - numba=0.38.0=py36h637b7d7_0
  - numexpr=2.6.5=py36h7bf3b9c_0
  - numpy=1.14.3=py36hcd700cb_1
  - numpy-base=1.14.3=py36h9be14a7_1
  - numpydoc=0.8.0=py36_0
  - odo=0.5.1=py36h90ed295_0
  - olefile=0.45.1=py36_0
  - openpyxl=2.5.3=py36_0
  - packaging=17.1=py36_0
  - pandas=0.23.0=py36h637b7d7_0
  - pandoc=1.19.2.1=hea2e7c5_1
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36ha6701b7_1
  - parso=0.2.0=py36_0
  - partd=0.3.8=py36h36fd896_0
  - patchelf=0.9=hf79760b_2
  - path.py=11.0.1=py36_0
  - pathlib2=2.3.2=py36_0
  - patsy=0.5.0=py36_0
  - pcre=8.42=h439df22_0
  - pep8=1.7.1=py36_0
  - persistent=4.2.4.2=py36h14c3975_0
  - pexpect=4.5.0=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h63277f8_0
  - pillow=5.1.0=py36h3deb7b8_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - pixman=0.34.0=hceecf20_3
  - pkginfo=1.4.2=py36_1
  - pluggy=0.6.0=py36hb689045_0
  - ply=3.11=py36_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h17d85b1_0
  - psutil=5.4.5=py36h14c3975_0
  - ptyprocess=0.5.2=py36h69acd42_0
  - py=1.5.3=py36_0
  - pycodestyle=2.4.0=py36_0
  - pycosat=0.6.3=py36h0a5515d_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36hf9f622e_1
  - pycrypto=2.6.1=py36h14c3975_8
  - pycurl=7.43.0.1=py36hb7f436b_0
  - pyflakes=1.6.0=py36h7bd6a15_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36h0d3125c_0
  - pylint=1.8.4=py36_0
  - pyodbc=4.0.23=py36hf484d3e_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36hee85983_1
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py36h751905a_0
  - pysocks=1.6.8=py36_0
  - pytables=3.4.3=py36h02b9ad4_2
  - pytest=3.5.1=py36_0
  - pytest-arraydiff=0.2=py36_0
  - pytest-astropy=0.3.0=py36_0
  - pytest-doctestplus=0.1.3=py36_0
  - pytest-openfiles=0.3.0=py36_0
  - pytest-remotedata=0.2.1=py36_0
  - python=3.6.5=hc3d631a_2
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.4=py36_0
  - pywavelets=0.5.2=py36he602eb0_0
  - pyyaml=3.12=py36hafb9ca4_1
  - pyzmq=17.0.0=py36h14c3975_0
  - qt=5.9.5=h7e424d6_0
  - qtawesome=0.4.4=py36h609ed8c_0
  - qtconsole=4.3.1=py36h8f73b5b_0
  - qtpy=1.4.1=py36_0
  - readline=7.0=ha6073c6_4
  - requests=2.18.4=py36he2e5f8d_1
  - rope=0.10.7=py36h147e2ec_0
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.35=py36h14c3975_1
  - scikit-image=0.13.1=py36h14c3975_1
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36h7aa7ec6_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36hfc37229_0
  - seaborn=0.8.1=py36hfad7ec4_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - setuptools=39.1.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py36h7a266c3_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py36hf484d3e_0
  - six=1.11.0=py36h372c433_1
  - snappy=1.1.7=hbae5bb6_3
  - snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py36h6febd40_0
  - sortedcollections=0.6.1=py36_0
  - sortedcontainers=1.5.10=py36_0
  - sphinx=1.7.4=py36_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py36h6d0f590_1
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.0.1=py36hb5cb234_1
  - spyder=3.2.8=py36_0
  - sqlalchemy=1.2.7=py36h6b74fdf_0
  - sqlite=3.23.1=he433501_0
  - statsmodels=0.9.0=py36h3010b51_0
  - sympy=1.1.1=py36hc6d1c1c_0
  - tblib=1.3.2=py36h34cf8b6_0
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h8cadb63_0
  - tk=8.6.7=hc745277_3
  - toolz=0.9.0=py36_0
  - tornado=5.0.2=py36_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h674d592_0
  - typing=3.6.4=py36_0
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1=py36ha668878_0
  - unixodbc=2.3.6=h1bed415_0
  - urllib3=1.22=py36hbe7ace6_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36hdf4376a_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36h800622e_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.2.1=py36_0
  - wrapt=1.10.11=py36h28b7045_0
  - xlrd=1.1.0=py36h1db9f0c_1
  - xlsxwriter=1.0.4=py36_0
  - xlwt=1.3.0=py36h7b00a1f_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - yaml=0.1.7=had09818_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=h439df22_0
  - zict=0.1.3=py36h3a3bf81_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=ha838bed_2
  - at-spi2-atk=2.18.1=2
  - at-spi2-core=2.18.3=2
  - atk=2.18.0=3
  - cairo-gobject=1.12.18=8
  - dbus-client=1.10.10=0
  - gdk-pixbuf=2.32.2=2
  - gobject-introspection=1.46.0=2
  - gtk3=3.14.15=4
  - libffi32=3.2.1=1
  - modern-xorg-stack=2016.03=1
  - pango=1.38.1=2
  - affinegap=1.10=py36h14c3975_0
  - categorical-distance=1.9=py36_0
  - dedupe=1.9.1=py36h14c3975_0
  - dedupe-hcluster=0.3.2=py36h14c3975_0
  - doublemetaphone=0.1=py36hf484d3e_0
  - fastcluster=1.1.24=py36hf484d3e_0
  - haversine=0.4.5=py36_0
  - highered=0.2.1=py36_0
  - levenshtein-search=1.4.4=py36h14c3975_0
  - pyhacrf-datamade=0.2.1=py36h14c3975_0
  - pylbfgs=0.2.0.5=py36h14c3975_0
  - rlr=2.4.3=py36_0
  - simplecosine=1.2=py36_0
  - zope.index=4.3.0=py36_0
  - pip:
    - alembic==0.8.10
    - configparser==3.5.0
    - croniter==0.3.25
    - datetime-distance==0.1.3
    - dedupe-variable-datetime==0.1.5
    - dill==0.2.8.2
    - flask-admin==1.4.1
    - flask-cache==0.13.1
    - flask-login==0.2.11
    - flask-swagger==0.2.13
    - flask-wtf==0.12
    - funcsigs==1.0.0
    - gitdb2==2.0.4
    - gitpython==2.1.11
    - gunicorn==19.3.0
    - lockfile==0.12.2
    - mako==1.0.7
    - markdown==2.6.11
    - msgpack==0.5.6
    - ordereddict==1.1
    - python-daemon==2.1.2
    - python-editor==1.0.3
    - python-nvd3==0.14.2
    - python-slugify==1.1.4
    - recordlinkage==0.11.2
    - smmap2==2.0.4
    - src==0.0.1
    - tables==3.4.3
    - tabulate==0.7.7
    - unidecode==1.0.22
    - wtforms==2.2.1
    - zope.deprecation==4.3.0
prefix: /home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/final_env
```

Comment: Do you mind showing the actual `environment.yml` file?

Comment: Also check the directory where jellyfish is installed in the new environment. On the IPython prompt, `jellyfish.__file__` or `jellyfish.__path__` should tell you. Then, have a look in that directory, and compare the files found there with those in the same (or similar) directory in the working environment.

Comment: Have you made sure that the other users `iPython` is using the correct interpreter (i.e. the freshly created environment's one)

Comment: I've included the requested items.

Comment: looking into a totally different issue with jellyfish - i just found out that bioconda's jellyfish is different from conda-forge's version - just two packages with the same name